# ¿ Pytest bloquea mi consola?

Tags: python, testing, unittest

Tengo un proyecto python y empecé a crear mis pruebas unitarias con pytest, pero cuando ejecuto el comando `pytest tests` se queda congelada la consola con los resultados, no me deja salir y tengo que cerrarla y volver a crear otra para poder trabajar.

Este es mi `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
addopts = --verbose
```

Ya intente cambiandolo por

```
[pytest]
pythonpath =
    "."
testpaths =
    tests
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Comment: Cuales son los test que tienes?

Comment: Son cosas sencillas, hasta dejé un assert True, solo por probar. Aunque por lo que veo es porque en __init__.py se inicia un socket y se queda abierto.

Comment: Pues efectivamente es eso. Para terminar el test el codigo debe de finalizar y si tienes un ciclo infinito pues nunca lo hará

Comment: La pregunta es, como puedo controlar el socket parar tambien probar lo que tengo sobre el socket?